# Look into vs Look at in the sentence below

Tags: american-english, british-english

Is the sentence

> I hope he will take a look at it?

correct? "It" refers to a problem at work. Is using *take a look at* a good substitute for *look into*?

Comment: Yes it is correct and they are synonymous.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that either "take a look at" or "look into" would work in the above sentence, but that's only because there's so little context.
I don't feel like the two phrases are synonymous. For example:

"Take a look at this example"="see this example I'm showing you"
"Look into this example"="there is a problem with this example and I want you to study it in order to resolve the problem"

So I agree with your teacher that "take a look at" has a physical object and "look into" has an abstract object.

Comment: If i recall correctly, the point was to use a phrasal verb that has the verb "look" in it as a substitute for the word "examine".

Comment: It sounds like a confusingly worded question. The object is just "it" and that's where all the difference lies. "I hope he will examine this problem"="I hope he will look into this problem" but "I hope he will examine this specimen"="I hope he will take a look at this specimen"

Answer (score 0):

They are synonyms. It is interesting to see the presence of ´look into´ shifting to ´take a look at´ along the decades in this Ngram.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+a+look+at%2C+look+into&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20a%20look%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clook%20into%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Thank you. My English teacher did not accept my answer due to a problem "being an abstract thing" and argued that when talking about abstract issues we use "look into." What do you think of this argument?